# How to get article intro image by article Id?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I'm trying to get Article's intro Image in Joomla 3.3 I found this code and it's not working:

```
$article = JTable::getInstance("content"); 
$article->load(JRequest::getInt("id")); // Get Article ID 
$article_images = $article->get("images"); // Get image parameters
$pictures = json_decode($article_images); // Split the parameters apart
// Print the image
echo "<img src='" . $pictures->{'image_intro'} . "' alt='" . $pictures->{'image_intro_alt'} . "'>";
```

I got info that `JRequest::getInt` is depreciated and i when i'm trying to var dump `$pictures` i got null. Can somebody tell me how to get 1 intro image by article id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JRequest` is **deprecated**.](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2#JRequest)

It's been replaced by [`JInput`](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput), so your line:

```
$article->load(JRequest::getInt("id")); // Get Article ID
```

would need to change to:

```
$id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('id');
$article->load($id); // Get Article
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use `JInput` but I think `JRequest` is valid right now (for Joomla 3.3).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure accessing the article is the issue, although you should use JInput veruses JRequest, it shouldn't prevent you from getting the data yet.  Unless there is a new technique I've missed in my old age, you are not referencing the image properties properly, try this:

```
echo "<img src='" . $pictures->image_intro . "' alt='" . $pictures->image_intro_alt . "'>";
```